# How to create a pop-up menu to get numerical input

Tags: python

I want to do it so that when they press a button a window comes up which says 'Subdivision Level' and then an input where whoever's using it can put in a number which changes how much subdivision to add.

Here's the code:

```
import bpy

class customMenu(bpy.types.Menu):
    bl_label = "Useful Menu"
    bl_idname = "view3D.custom_menu"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        layout.operator("bpy.ops.object.subdivision_set(level=1")
        layout.operator("object.duplicate_move")

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(customMenu)
    #bpy.ops.wm.call_menu(name=customMenu.bl_idname)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(customMenu)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

I know how to do everything else I'm just confused about how to make something which allows people to put in inputs/make a slider/make a check box in blender python.

I don't mind if as an answer you just put the code on how to make these input types or if you link a wiki article or something. I'm just having problems finding the right website and I'm pretty sure it can be done.

Here's a link to the [blender tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pim5YIfWv-M) that I currently want the input for. So that when I click something on the mini-menu, another mini-menu-thing will open asking how much levels you want and if you want it simple or catmull-clark etc.

I'm sorry if it's obvious but I couldn't find an answer anywhere.

Comment: you are creating an addon right ?

Comment: @Chebhou not sure to be honest. I'm following a tutorial (I'll edit the question so it has a link to it) i think I'm just creating a little menu thing, like the ones where you press shift-a.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to call invoke\_popup?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6512/how-to-call-invoke-popup)

Comment: also related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23974/how-do-i-get-invoke-props-popup-to-work/23976#23976

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create an operator which will show a menu when called , this is the Simple Operator example edited to fit this case :

[image]

- Run the script to rigster the operator
- press <kbd>Space</kbd> and type `Simple Object Operator`

---

```
import bpy
from bpy.props import IntProperty

def main(self, context):
    bpy.ops.object.subdivision_set(level=self.level)

class SimpleOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "object.simple_operator"
    bl_label = "Simple Object Operator"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}
    
    level = IntProperty(default = 1, min = 0, max = 10)
    
    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.active_object is not None

    def execute(self, context):
        main(self, context)
        return {'FINISHED'}
    
    def invoke(self, context, event):
        wm = context.window_manager
        return wm.invoke_props_dialog(self)

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(SimpleOperator)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SimpleOperator)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

### For 2.8~

```
import bpy
from bpy.props import IntProperty

def main(self, context):
    bpy.ops.object.subdivision_set(level=self.level)

class SimpleOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "object.simple_operator"
    bl_label = "Simple Object Operator"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    level : IntProperty(default = 1, min = 0, max = 10)

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.active_object is not None

    def execute(self, context):
        main(self, context)
        return {'FINISHED'}

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        wm = context.window_manager
        return wm.invoke_props_dialog(self)

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(SimpleOperator)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SimpleOperator)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: I'll check it tomorrow. Sorry I can't do it today

Comment: Wait where are you supposed to put this? I'll edit my finished code into the question so you can see.

Comment: @Chickenator sorry this was for the operator but you are creating a menu I think it does not support this