# How can I make a dialog window make changes in real time?

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

Watching a tutorial from youtube I managed to setup an **addon** with a **tab** into `VIEW_3D` > `UI`, which contains a **panel** with some **buttons** (`operators`) where if you press any of them, you get a different **dialog** window with some **properties**, **labels** etc.

[image]

What I want to do is to have the ability to **see changes** in **real time** and not when I press OK. Something like this...

[image]

Is that possible? And if yes, how can I do that? Because I tried to execute my action through `draw` method but I get this error `AttributeError: Writing to ID classes in this context is not allowed: Scene, Scene datablock, error setting LayerCollection.hide_viewport`.

Here is an example of my code...

```
class fu3dm_WM_OT_Model_Prefs_Operator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "wm.fu3dm_model_prefs"
    bl_label = "Model Preferences"
    bl_description = "Blah blah blah"

    fu3dm_model_gender : bpy.props.EnumProperty(name="Gender", description="Choose model's gender", items= [('OP1', "Male", ""), ('OP2', "Female", "")], default='OP1')
    fu3dm_model_head_male : bpy.props.EnumProperty(name="Head", description="Choose model's head", items= [('OP1', "Generic Male", ""), ('OP2', "Christiano Ronaldo", "")], default='OP2')
    fu3dm_model_head_female : bpy.props.EnumProperty(name="Head", description="Choose model's head", items= [('OP1', "Generic Female", ""), ('OP2', "Ashlyn Harris", "")], default='OP2')
    fu3dm_model_eyes_color : bpy.props.IntProperty(name="Eyes Color", description="Choose model's eyes color", min=1, max=10, default=1)
    fu3dm_model_skin_color: bpy.props.IntProperty(name="Skin Color", description="Choose model's skin color", min=1, max=10, default=1)
    fu3dm_model_upper_body : bpy.props.EnumProperty(name="Upper Body", description="Choose model's upper body mesh", items= [('OP1', "Arms for Long Sleeves", ""), ('OP2', "Arms for Short Sleeves", ""), ('OP3', "Full Upper Body", "")], default='OP2')
    fu3dm_model_lower_body : bpy.props.EnumProperty(name="Lower Body", description="Choose model's lower body mesh", items= [('OP1', "Legs without Socks", ""), ('OP2', "Legs with Low Socks", ""), ('OP3', "Legs with Short Socks", ""), ('OP4', "Legs with Medium Socks", ""), ('OP5', "Legs with Long Socks", ""), ('OP6', "Legs with Medium Socks but without Shinpads", ""), ('OP7', "Full Lower Body", "")], default='OP4')
    
    def invoke(self, context, event):
        return context.window_manager.invoke_props_dialog(self)
        bpy.ops.wm.fu3dm_model_prefs('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
    
    def draw(self, context):    
        layout = self.layout    
        box = layout.box()
        col = box.column()

        row = col.split()
        row.label(text="Gender:")
        row.prop(self, "fu3dm_model_gender", text="")

        if self.fu3dm_model_gender == 'OP1':
            row = col.split()
            row.label(text="Head:")
            row.prop(self, "fu3dm_model_head_male", text="")
            self.do_it(self=self, context=context)
        else:
            row = col.split()
            row.label(text="Head:")
            row.prop(self, "fu3dm_model_head_female", text="")
            self.do_it(self=self, context=context)

        row = col.split()
        row.label(text="Eyes Color:")
        row.prop(self, "fu3dm_model_eyes_color", text="")

        row = col.split()
        row.label(text="Skin Color:")
        row.prop(self, "fu3dm_model_skin_color", text="")

        row = col.split()
        row.label(text="Upper Body:")
        row.prop(self, "fu3dm_model_upper_body", text="")

        row = col.split()
        row.label(text="Lower Body:")
        row.prop(self, "fu3dm_model_lower_body", text="")

    def execute(self, context):
        pass
        return {"FINISHED"}

    @staticmethod
    def do_it(self, context):
        vlayer = bpy.context.scene.view_layers['View Layer']
        if self.fu3dm_model_gender == 'OP1':
            vlayer.layer_collection.children['MALE'].hide_viewport = False
            vlayer.layer_collection.children['FEMALE'].hide_viewport = True
        else:
            vlayer.layer_collection.children['MALE'].hide_viewport = True
            vlayer.layer_collection.children['FEMALE'].hide_viewport = False
```

**Please keep in mind that I am totally new to blender and python!!!**

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23974/how-do-i-get-invoke-props-popup-to-work

Comment: As a side note, your `do_it` method shouldn't be a static method and the second line of your `invoke` method is never executed since it is written after a return statement

Comment: First of all, most likely just copied from a bad tutorial (link would be helpful), replace `bpy.context.*` by `context.*` Why `do_it()` method has a decorator? Recommend split up your question into multiple ones and always provide a *minimal* working example to make your question useful to others too.

Comment: @batFINGER thank you for the link very useful!!!

@Gorgious so I have to add `do_it` as a simple function, right? Excuse me for the `invoke` method. I am totally new to python and as brockmann said, I obviously copy it from a bad tutorial! Do I have to keep it anyway? Because if I use `bl_options = {'REGISTER','UNDO'}` as @mugnozzo wrote below, everything goes fine.

@brockmann yes, I probably copied from couple of bad tutorials, because isn't just one and in combination with my irrelevance, this ugly thing came up! I will add `do_it` to a simple function, I got it.

Comment: IMO doit should instead be the execute method.  Changing props fires the execute method.  https://pasteall.org/VSiA

Comment: So you say I have to add everything from `do_it` into `execute` method and not make a separate function?

Comment: Can call any other method from execute.  The execute method gets fired when props change.   To throw a spanner in the works: defining a property group with update methods on properties,  and layout  in a sub-panel  may be a more robust approach to setting preferences.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set a *Redo Panel*.

In [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xscQ9tcN4GI) Sybren shows how to create an operator with a redo panel ([at 8:17](https://youtu.be/xscQ9tcN4GI?t=497) he starts talking about it)

At [13:38](https://youtu.be/xscQ9tcN4GI?t=805) he talks exactly about what you need. Basicly you need to add:

```
bl_options = {'REGISTER','UNDO'}
```

after your `bl_description`.

Comment: I did not know that is called `Redo Panel`. Thank you very much for your answer. Solved my problem. One more question. Do I have to keep this `def invoke(self, context, event): ...etc` anyway? Because I removed it and I added `bl_options = {'REGISTER','UNDO'}`and works fine!!!

Comment: @SimonetosTheGreek use invoke to have a popup at location of mouse event (eg link posted in q comment with invoke props popup)  Without defaults to the bottom LH corner in 3D view.