# Is it possible to add a sub panel into a redo panel?

Tags: python, scripting, 3d-view, add-on

Is it possible to add a **sub panel** into a **redo panel**? If so, any kind of **example**, **tutorial**, **link** etc would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Even if *you think* that's a simple question, it's always harder getting into it for us without any sketch or example code. There are a lot possibilities as well as limitations as you might know by now.

Comment: AFAIK the answer is no. The "redo panel" is an operator (`bpy.types.Operator`), a subpanel requires a parent that is a panel (`bpy.types.Panel`)  _Can emulate a subpanel with conditionals in draw method, but it's not a real subpanel_  Way back commented here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/196824/how-can-i-make-a-dialog-window-make-changes-in-real-time#comment330059_196824 that perhaps using an operator approach for prefs was flawed and to consider making a prop group for this. Other issues have popped up re using the operator approach _ie_ using the value of one in another

Comment: and here once again, another issue.  My feeling is trying to use an operator redo panel for everything kinda makes you a  _A one trick pony down a rabbit hole_  Here is a recent answer re using the panel popover which in assoc with setting up pref property group would be perfect preferences https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/197265/blender-python-api-custom-gui/197283#197283

Comment: @batFINGER in other words your advice is not to use **redo panel** when have to make something like [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ztSSU84ciSbXSYq-rCzl1XtXvCPgm7Se/view?usp=sharing)? And that it would be better to work at the **n panel** for example?

Comment: The linked image never loads for me.  Advice is to consider it. IIRC I have mentioned also to look at code of add sapling addon that (last I looked) uses one monster redo panel. (All options available in one operator)  A lot depends on what your addon does. Recommend finding an addon that does the same / similar and investigate the code.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ztSSU84ciSbXSYq-rCzl1XtXvCPgm7Se/view

Comment: @batFINGER there is no monster redo panel anymore (depending on what do you mean by monster). I have "break" the whole thing to parts. Properties also have "broke" into property groups. Generally I changed everything according to your advises and your examples like this one ( https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/183773/trying-to-make-a-menu-using-multiple-modules/183817#183817 ). I just wanted to add sub panels into redo panels for decorative purposes. Anyway, I made it with labels, arrow icons and some boolean so to emulate the fold and unfold actions.

Comment: @brockmann excuse me that I didn't edit my question so to add more details as you asked me to do. I didn't ignore you. After your comment I started to edit my question, but then I got batFINGER's comment who wrote that isn't possible, so I stopped the update of my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't imagine why my question has been downvoted, but anyway...

I wanted to add a sub panel into a redo panel, mainly for decorative purposes. As batFINGER said, this can't be done. So I made a fake sub panel with a label, an icon and a boolean.

Here is a code example of how I made it, if anyone wants to do something similar:

```
import bpy

class MYADDON_properties(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    fold : bpy.props.BoolProperty(name="fold", default=0)
    
class MYADDON_PT_main_panel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_idname = "myaddon.main_panel"
    bl_label = "Fake Sub Panel for Redo Panel"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_category = "MYADDON"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        row = layout.row()
        row.operator("MYADDON.operator")

class MYADDON_OT_operator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "myaddon.operator"
    bl_label = "Operator"
    bl_description = "Operator"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER','UNDO'}

    def draw(self, context):
        my_props = context.window_manager.myaddon_properties
        
        layout = self.layout
        row = layout.row()
        row.split()
        row.alignment = 'RIGHT'
        if my_props.fold:
            row.operator("MYADDON.unfold", text="", emboss=False, icon='DISCLOSURE_TRI_RIGHT')
        else:
            row.operator("MYADDON.fold", text="", emboss=False, icon='DISCLOSURE_TRI_DOWN')
        row.alignment = 'LEFT'
        row.label(text="Fake Sub Panel")
        if not my_props.fold:
            col = layout.column(align=True)
            col.label(text="Label #1")
            col.label(text="Label #2")
            col.label(text="Label #3")

    def execute(self, context):
        return {"FINISHED"}

class MYADDON_OT_fold(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "myaddon.fold"
    bl_label = ""
    bl_description = ""

    def execute(self, context):
        my_props = context.window_manager.myaddon_properties
        my_props.fold = True
        return {"FINISHED"}

class MYADDON_OT_unfold(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "myaddon.unfold"
    bl_label = ""
    bl_description = ""

    def execute(self, context):
        my_props = context.window_manager.myaddon_properties
        my_props.fold = False
        return {"FINISHED"}

classes = (
    MYADDON_properties,
    MYADDON_OT_operator,
    MYADDON_OT_fold,
    MYADDON_OT_unfold,
    MYADDON_PT_main_panel,
)

def register():
    from bpy.utils import register_class
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)
    bpy.types.WindowManager.myaddon_properties = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type = MYADDON_properties)

def unregister():
    from bpy.utils import unregister_class
    for cls in classes:
        unregister_class(cls)
    del bpy.types.WindowManager.myaddon_properties
```

If someone has any kind of corrections or suggestions...